# joomla 1.7 : override a module helper.php

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I want to override a `helper.php` file of a module, exactly

> \administrator\modules\mod_quickicon\helper.php

what I want is to update the getButtons function in this file

what are the options I have to override this particular file ? its possible using a plugin ?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can really only do a template override on the file in the tmpl folder called default.php.  If you want to override helper.php, you're essentially rewriting the module itself.  This isn't necessarily a bad thing, just copy the contents of the existing helper.php file into another file for backup, and hack away.  The downside of doing this is that if someone updates the module, and you install that update, you'll have to redo your hack.  Again, it's not that hard to work around.  Just backup backup backup.

Some more thoughts:
You could also do the following:
1) Copy the module to a different folder, beginning with mod_ as well, but with a different name.
2) Modify the xml file, helper file, component file (and any others that are necessary) to account for the new name.  Also do whatever you want to helper.php.
3) Go to extension manager and do a discover install of this new module
4) Go to module manager and make a new instance of the new module (using the same position as the old one).
5) Unpublish the module you're replacing

Doing this will keep you safe from update loss.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I've done with Joomla! 3.3.1 but it might be done with Joomla! 1.7, too:

- Copy `default.php` from

  ```
  /administrator/modules/mod_quickicon/tmpl/
  ```

  to

  ```
  /administrator/templates/YOUR_ADMIN_TEMPLATE_NAME/html/mod_quickicon/
  ```
- Open the copied file and replace the line below

  ```
  $html = JHtml::_('links.linksgroups', ModQuickIconHelper::groupButtons($buttons));
  ```

  with these lines:

  ```
  $myLinks = array(
      'YOUR_QUICKICON_GROUP_NAME' => array(
          array(
              'link' => JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_YOURCOMPONENT'),
              'image' => 'stack',
              'icon' => 'header/icon-48-article-add.png',
              'text' => JText::_('YOUR_QUICKICON_ITEM_NAME'),
              'access' => array('core.manage', 'com_YOURCOMPONENT'),
              'group' => 'YOUR_QUICKICON_GROUP_NAME'
          )
      )
  );

  $array = ModQuickIconHelper::groupButtons($buttons);
  $array = array_merge($myLinks, $array);

  $html = JHtml::_('links.linksgroups', $array);
  ```

That's it. You can edit or create `/administrator/language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini` and add these lines:

```
YOUR_QUICKICON_GROUP_NAME="The Group"
YOUR_QUICKICON_ITEM_NAME="The Item"
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Your solution works to overwrite a template but not a helper. See: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core